# How to avg and then order data in SQL if it can appear in two columns?

Tags: sql, sqlite

So I have table `points` with columns like `person1_id person2_id team_score` and you can see that one person can appear in `person1_id` or `person2_id` column because the player can be in multiple teams, so the question is how do I get the top n players with highest `average_score` which is defined by the average of all the team_score he|she participated in?   like `person_id average_score`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tim's answer is a very good answer.  But, assuming that you have a `persons` table, you can do this without `union all`:

```
select p.person_id,
       (select avg(team_score)
        from points po
        where p.person_id in (po.person1_id, po.person2_id)
       ) as average_score
from persons p
order by average_score desc
limit 5;  -- or whatever
```

A rather more complicated expression is probably the most efficient:

```
select p.person_id,
       ( (select sum(team_score)
          from points po
          where p.person_id = po.person1_id
         ) +
         (select sum(team_score)
          from points po
          where p.person_id = po.person2_id
         )
       ) /
       nullif( (select count(*)
                from points po
                where p.person_id = po.person1_id
               ) +
               (select count(*)
                from points po
                where p.person_id = po.person2_id
               ), 0
             ) as average_score
from persons p
order by average_score desc
limit 5;
```

The reason this is more efficient is that it can make use of indexes on `points(person1_id, team_score)` and `points(person2_id, team_score)`.

Comment: @forpas . . . Yes.  With the stated indexes *and enough data*, I can be serious.

Comment: *With the stated indexes* why are the other answers less efficient?

Comment: Because indexes are generally not used for `or`, `in`, or `union`s (although they might be used for `union all` with filtering).

Answer (score 2):

One approach uses a union to create a single logical column of all players and their scores:

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    AVG(team_score) AS average_score
FROM
(
    SELECT person1_id AS person_id, team_score FROM points
    UNION ALL
    SELECT person2_id, team_score FROM points
) t
GROUP BY
    person_id
ORDER BY
    AVG(team_score) DESC
LIMIT 10;   -- e.g. for the top 10, but you may replace 10 with any value you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You might solve your problem with a `coalesce` function, something like:

```
SELECT    
  COALESCE(person1_id, person2_id) AS person_id,  
  AVG(team_score) as average_score 
FROM points  
GROUP BY COALESCE(person1_id, person2_id)
ORDER BY AVG(team_score)
```

What's going on here is `COALESCE(col1, col2)` returns the first non-null column in the list. You can do this with as many columns as you like.

Here are the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all the distinct palyers and then join them to the `points` table:

```
select 
  d.id person_id, 
  avg(p.team_score) avgscore 
from (
  select person1_id id from points
  union
  select person2_id id from points
) d inner join points p
on (p.person1_id = d.id) or (p.person2_id = d.id)
group by d.id
order by avgscore desc
limit 3
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rtXVHEZVcK8gDdnysBQyms/1)